# Getting: bad option; for several filesystems (e.g. nfs, cifs) when trying to mount azure file share in K8 container

Tags: azure, kubernetes, azure-aks, persistent-volumes, azure-files

I created a Azure file share and I am able to connect to it using map network drive in my laptop having windows 10. I created a hello-world spring boot application with volume mount configurations for azure file share and trying to deploy in Kubernetes in docker-desktop. But my pod doesn't starts -

```
hello-world-9d7479c4d-26mv2   0/1     ContainerCreating   0          15s
```

Here is the error I can see in events when I describe the POD -

```
Events:
  Type     Reason       Age              From                     Message
  ----     ------       ----             ----                     -------
  Normal   Scheduled    9h                                        Successfully assigned default/hello-world-9d7479c4d-26mv2 to docker-desktop
  Warning  FailedMount  9h (x7 over 9h)  kubelet, docker-desktop  MountVolume.SetUp failed for volume "fileshare-pv" : mount failed: exit status 32
Mounting command: mount
Mounting arguments: -t cifs -o file_mode=0777,dir_mode=0777,vers=3.0,<masked> //mystorage.file.core.windows.net/myshare /var/lib/kubelet/pods/425012d1-13ee-4c40-bf40-d2f7ccfe5954/volumes/kubernetes.io~azure-file/fileshare-pv
Output: mount: /var/lib/kubelet/pods/425012d1-13ee-4c40-bf40-d2f7ccfe5954/volumes/kubernetes.io~azure-file/fileshare-pv: bad option; for several filesystems (e.g. nfs, cifs) you might need a /sbin/mount.<type> helper program.
```

Then I updated my Dockerfile to install cifs-utils -

```
FROM ubuntu:16.04
# Install Java
RUN apt-get update && \
    apt-get install -y openjdk-8-jdk && \
    apt-get install -y ant && \
    apt-get install -y cifs-utils && \
    apt-get clean;

ENV PORT 8080
EXPOSE 8080
COPY target/*.jar /opt/app.jar
WORKDIR /opt
CMD ["java", "-jar", "app.jar"]
```

Still that error doesn't go. I googled a lot for solution but no luck. Is there any limitation in using azure file share with kubernates container in docker-desktop [windows machine]?

Here are my K8 configurations -

**secret.yaml**

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Secret
metadata:
  name: storage-secret
  namespace: default
type: Opaque
data:
  azurestorageaccountname: BASE64-encoded-account-name
  azurestorageaccountkey: BASE64-encoded-account-key
```

**pv.yaml**

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: PersistentVolume
metadata:
  name: fileshare-pv
  labels:
    usage: fileshare-pv
spec:
  capacity:
    storage: 1Gi
  accessModes:
    - ReadWriteMany
  persistentVolumeReclaimPolicy: Retain
  azureFile:
    secretName: storage-secret
    shareName: myshare
    readOnly: false
```

**pvc.yaml**

```
kind: PersistentVolumeClaim
apiVersion: v1
metadata:
  name: fileshare-pvc
  namespace: default
  # Set this annotation to NOT let Kubernetes automatically create
  # a persistent volume for this volume claim.
  annotations:
    volume.beta.kubernetes.io/storage-class: ""
spec:
  accessModes:
    - ReadWriteMany
  resources:
    requests:
      storage: 1Gi
  selector:
    # To make sure we match the claim with the exact volume, match the label
    matchLabels:
      usage: fileshare-pv
```

**deployment.yaml**

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: hello-world
  namespace: default
  labels:
    app: hello-world
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: hello-world
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: hello-world
    spec:
      containers:
        - name: hello-world-pod
          image: 'hello-world-k8:1.0'
          volumeMounts:
          - name: azure
            mountPath: /azureshare
          ports:
            - containerPort: 8080
      volumes:
      - name: azure
        persistentVolumeClaim:
          claimName: fileshare-pvc      
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: hello-world-service
  namespace: default
spec:
  selector:
    app: hello-world
  ports:
  - name: http
    protocol: TCP
    port: 8080
    targetPort: 8080
  type: LoadBalancer
```

Answer (score 17):

You likely need to install a package that knows how to mount that file system. For NFS this may be nfs-common with Debian/Ubuntu.

`sudo apt update && sudo apt install nfs-common -y`

Comment: For Centos8, the command is: `sudo yum install nfs-utils`

Comment: `cifs-utils` for Ubuntu 22 LTS if mounting SMB/CIFS drive. `cifs-utils` provide both CIFS and SMB3 types. `ls /sbin/mount.*` to see installed mount types.

Answer (score 0):

It happened on my ubuntu server 22.04 LTS machine. Use `sudo apt install nfs-common` or `sudo apt install nfs-utils` to resolve it.